# Getting invalid identifier and SQL ignored errors in stored procedure in Oracle

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g

I am trying to create a stored procedure in order to insert some data into some table in Oracle 11g.

For this purpose, I need to read the last amount from the latest insert for that user, and then add it to my new value and save the changes as a new row and if any kind of exception is occurred just rollback. This is what I have come up with so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYTESTDB.INSERT_INTO_TESTBANK
(
  ID IN TBLTESTBANK.ID%TYPE,
  USERID IN TBLTESTBANK.USERID%TYPE,
  TYPE IN TBLTESTBANK.TYPE%TYPE,
  AMOUNT IN TBLTESTBANK.AMOUNT%TYPE,
  DATETIMESTAMP IN TBLTESTBANK.DATETIMESTAMP%TYPE,
  TRANSACTION_ID IN TBLTESTBANK.IDTRANS%TYPE,
  TOTAL_MONEY IN TBLTESTBANK.TOTALMONEY%TYPE,
  COMPUTED_HASH IN TBLTESTBANK.HASH%TYPE
  )
IS

BEGIN
  DECLARE 
  LastAmount TBLTESTBANK.TOTALMONEY%TYPE;

  BEGIN
      SELECT TBLTESTBANK.TOTALMONEY INTO LASTAMOUNT
      FROM 
      (
        SELECT TBLTESTBANK.ID 
        FROM TBLTESTBANK tblbnk
        WHERE tblbnk.USERID = USERID 
        order by max(tblbnk.DATETIMESTAMP)
      ) 
      where ROWNUM<2;
      EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND 
      THEN LastAmount := 0;        
   END;

  LastAmount := LastAmount+ AMOUNT;

  INSERT INTO TBLTESTBANK (ID, USERID, TYPE, LastAmount,
                            DATETIMESTAMP, IDTRANS, TOTALMONEY, HASH
                            )
  VALUES (ID, USERID, TYPE, AMOUNT, DATETIMESTAMP, TRANSACTION_ID, TOTAL_MONEY, COMPUTED_HASH); 
    COMMIT;
 EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS
  THEN
  ROLLBACK;
END;
/
```

Whenever I try to test it, I get a red wiggly line under the first SELECT , and then he TESTBANK.ID in the inner select statements. For the select command it says, sql statement is ignored, and for the TESTBANK.ID it says invalid identifier!

It also doesn't let me add two variables, and keeps saying LastAmount must be declared.

And these are the errors I get :

```
     Error(19,7): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
     Error(22,16): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "TBLTESTBANK"."ID": invalid identifier
     Error(32,3): PLS-00201: identifier 'LASTAMOUNT' must be declared
     Error(32,3): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
     Error(34,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
     Error(34,47): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "LASTAMOUNT": invalid identifier
```

Comment: Please post the complete and exact error message.

Comment: @a_horse_no_name: I updated the question with the errors i get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

In your select statement:

```
   SELECT TBLTESTBANK.ID 
    FROM TBLTESTBANK tblbnk
    WHERE tblbnk.USERID = USERID 
    order by max(tblbnk.DATETIMESTAMP)
```

You have given the table `TBLTESTBANK` the alias `tblbnk` therefor you must use the alias throughout the statement:

```
   SELECT tblbnk.ID  -- use the correct alias here
    FROM TBLTESTBANK tblbnk
    WHERE tblbnk.USERID = USERID 
    order by max(tblbnk.DATETIMESTAMP)
```

Second:

in the `INSERT` statement you have to list *columns* not values.

```
INSERT INTO TBLTESTBANK (ID, USERID, TYPE, LastAmount,
                        DATETIMESTAMP, IDTRANS, TOTALMONEY, HASH
                        )
```

should be:

```
INSERT INTO TBLTESTBANK (ID, USERID, TYPE, AMOUNT, --- column name instead of variable name
                        DATETIMESTAMP, IDTRANS, TOTALMONEY, HASH
                        )
```

And then of course you need to use `LastAmount` in the values part, not `AMOUNT`

In general it's not a good idea to have variables with the same name as columns of tables that you use in the procedure. It's easy to shadow a variable with a column. You should rename the variables to avoid any problems there.

**Edit** (I didn't notice this at first).

You also have an error in the structure of the code. A stored procedure (or function) does not have a `DECLARE` section:

Your declaration needs to look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYTESTDB.INSERT_INTO_TESTBANK
(
  ....
)
IS
  -- no DECLARE
  -- variables right after the IS keyword
  LastAmount TBLTESTBANK.TOTALMONEY%TYPE;
BEGIN

...
END;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved the select issue, But I am still having the LATESTAMOUNT must be declared error!!

Comment: @Hossein Did change the column list for the `insert` statement?

Comment: Yes i did. I also changed the variable names so that they dont collide or shadow each other.: This is the latest changes :http://pastebin.com/tLwNZzfC

Comment: @Hossein: see my edit. No offense, but you should **really** read the PL/SQL manual (again). All those syntax elements are explained there in great detail and with examples.

Comment: Thanks, I'm grateful. Yes you are right, actually i just have a very basic knowledge on oracle. im just learning as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below select query to get latest record.

```
SELECT TB.TOTALMONEY INTO LASTAMOUNT
FROM 
TESTBANK TB
WHERE
TB.USERID=USERID
AND
DATETIMESTAMP= (SELECT MAX       (TB2.DATETIMESTAMP) FROM TESTBANK TB2 
WHERE TB2.USERID=USERID);
```